# Is there a way of showing all data of a row from a column chart in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization

I'm trying to replicate the UI of a website chart (the following image):
[image: All the data of the row shows while hovering]

I'm working in Google Sheets and I have imported the same data used in the creation of the chart above, however I couldn't figure out how to add to the hover label (? I'm not sure I'm calling it right...) all the data I wanted.

Right now the chart in my Google Sheets only shows the Net Amplitude data when hovering. Can you please direct me to add the rest?

Comment: Are you asking how to fit the data into your chart or how to change the label description? It would be helpful to see your spreadsheet with your chart.

Comment: I want for the label that pops up whenever I hover over a line (in this case) to include all the info in the image above. In my Google Sheets chart it only shows the "Net Amplitude", but I want it to also show "Starting Time", "Ending Time", "Percentage Amplitude", "Starting Price", "Ending Price" and "Actual Duration".

Comment: Hey Rus, tried my end. I think its a limitation by google sheets

Comment: Agreed, you cannot do it wiht Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the comments from below my question, I can only conclude that Google Sheets has this limitation. Consider this an answer, although the credit should go to @ziganotschka and @Nami888 for taking the time to confirm my suspicions.